# Node.js + Socket.io | Set custom headers on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, engine.io

I use Helmet with Express to set quite some security HTTP headers from the server side. This is nicely done, when rendering client pages on top of the node.js app, using:

```
var app = express();
app.use(helmet());
..
res.render("pages/index", data);
```

All the resources on the index page will have the Helmet headers. Unfortunately, socket.io does its own header management. So, anything that comes after /socket.io/ will have insecure/its own headers. For example here:

```
<https_path>/socket.io/socket.io.js
<https_path>/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lj4CFnj&sid=ILskOFWbHUaU6grTAAAA
```

Hence, I want to set custom headers for all socket.io items manually.

This is how I require socket.io (excerpt only):

/src/app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var sio = require("socket.io");
var app = express();
var io = require("./../lib/io.js").initialize(app.listen(REST_PORT, () => {
    logger.info("Application ready on port " + REST_PORT + " . Environment: " + NODE_ENV);
}));
```

/lib/io.js

```
exports = module.exports = {};
var sio = require("socket.io");
exports.initialize = function(server) {
    var options = {
        cookie: false,
        extraHeaders: {
        "X-Custom-Header-For-My-Project": "Custom stuff",
        }
    };
    io = sio(server, options);
    io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    // logic
)};
```

The "extraHeaders" option doesn´t work, I guess it could only with socket.io-client. I did large amount of googling around, but not luck on this.

Also looked around how to use socket.request (apparently it helps with headers, according to: [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/)), but I couldn´t figure that out either.

Could you guys help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

extraHeaders options will work as below, as you need to remove "transports: ['polling']," in case you are using, and use below pattern. This worked for me, and was able to send custom headers.

package used :-  "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",

```
this.socket = io(environment.host, {
   path: `/api/backend/socket.io`,
   origins: '*:*',
   // transports: ['polling'],
   transportOptions: {
     polling: {
        extraHeaders: {
           'authorization': token,
           'user-id' : userId
        }
     }
    }
 })
```

Ref:- https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-extraHeaders