# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have a socket.io server running and I cannot connect to it form my local html file on my mac.

Error:

> Failed to load
>   http://file/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M6tFqlm: The value of
>   the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be
>   the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
>   Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of
>   requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the
>   withCredentials attribute.

Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = app.listen(8080);
var cors = require('cors');

app.options('*', cors());
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

....

// think this is redudant
server.listen(8080);
```

Local HTML file (no local server running it)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="../socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    // Create SocketIO instance, connect

    // var socket = new io.Socket();
    var socket = io();


    //var socket = io('https://example.com:8080', { transport : ['websocket'] });
    socket.connect('https://example.com:8080'); 

    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('connect',function() {
      console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
    });
    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('message',function(data) {
      console.log('Received a message from the server!',data);
    });
    // Add a disconnect listener
    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
      console.log('The client has disconnected!');
    });

    // Sends a message to the server via sockets
    function sendMessageToServer(message) {
      socket.send(message);
    };
</script>
  <div id="date"></div>
  <textarea id="text"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `<script src="../socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>` to `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: Finding the socket.io client js file isn't the issue. The error is because of cross browser request. I tried the CORS chrome plugins but they do not help.

Comment: Ok. Next, have you changed this `app.options('*', cors());` to `app.use(cors());`?

Comment: Yes and failed.

Comment: Is your node websocket server running in multiple instances (cluster mode) or fork mode? I have encountered a problem similar to this before

Comment: It is running on AWS ALB (not ELB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials) you have **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials** header set to *include* which requires a server to specify that this domain can access cookies etc. - which makes sense - you don't want to send cookies or credentials to just **any** site.

If you only have an HTML file that's is not hosted anywhere all you can do is disable credentials, so they are not sent. I've looked on [the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35381472/4443323) and I think you can set it like:

```
var socket = io({
  extraHeaders: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'omit'
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could just disable CORS in a browser, but of course, it's last resort technique which opens yourself to security issues.

Comment: The above code is for the client? I tried the CORS chrome plugins but they did not work.

Comment: @jdog yes, for the client.

Comment: For anyone looking for the solution. This answer worked for me. However, I had to use a CORS plugin in Firefox along with the code. Chrome CORS plugins did not ever work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of pain with CORS

but you should set a specific domain and it will help you a lot.

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (any_logic_you_want) {
      //this is not tested, just copied from npm cors docs
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: I am trying that exact code right now. The issue is I am using an html page off my website so setting something in whitelist will not work as it is not running from a specific domain. I assume the above example1.com is the domain of the client not the server correct?

Comment: yap, my bad. removed it. in this situation, I assume it suppose to set the domain you are accessing with so you will be good. No whitelist here, just setting the domain that was accessed with into cors